# Revert all files with a specified name

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, command-line-interface, revert

Hi i want to revert all changes to the files with a specific filename in a local repository.
In this case `AssemblyInfo.vb`, i'm using the `TortoiseSVN` cli.

I have the following directory structure

- Root

  - Project 1

    - File1.txt
    - My Project

      - AssemblyInfo.vb
  - Project 2

    - File2.txt
    - My Project

      - AssemblyInfo.vb

Now while standing in `Root` i run the command `svn.exe revert --recursive AssemblyInfo.vb` and the output i get is:

`Skipped 'AssemblyInfo.vb'`

I have tried to add double and single `*` before the filename with no success, does `--recursive`/`-R` work or what am i missing?

`svn help revert` gives the following output:

```
revert: Restore pristine working copy state (undo local changes).
usage: revert PATH...

  Revert changes in the working copy at or within PATH, and remove
  conflict markers as well, if any.

  This subcommand does not revert already committed changes.
  For information about undoing already committed changes, search
  the output of 'svn help merge' for 'undo'.

Valid options:
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  -R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                             'immediates', or 'infinity')
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  --changelist [--cl] ARG  : operate only on members of changelist ARG

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG (caution: on many operating
                             systems, other users will be able to see this)
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting (default is to prompt
                             only if standard input is a terminal device)
  --force-interactive      : do interactive prompting even if standard input
                             is not a terminal device
  --trust-server-cert      : deprecated; same as
                             --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca
  --trust-server-cert-failures ARG : with --non-interactive, accept SSL server
                             certificates with failures; ARG is comma-separated
                             list of 'unknown-ca' (Unknown Authority),
                             'cn-mismatch' (Hostname mismatch), 'expired'
                             (Expired certificate), 'not-yet-valid' (Not yet
                             valid certificate) and 'other' (all other not
                             separately classified certificate errors).
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
  --config-option ARG      : set user configuration option in the format:
                                 FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]
                             For example:
                                 servers:global:http-library=serf
```

If i run `svn.exe revert --recursive AssemblyInfo.vb` in a directory that directly contains a modified `AssemblyInfo.vb` it works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) is designed to help *fix* mistakes, not cause problems by "helping" users to accidentally or unintentionally remove their local and uncommitted changes.

If you want to revert *all* the changes in your SVN working copy or in a directory and all its childs, you could run `svn revert . -R`. But you must not run this command if your working copy has a mixture of valid uncommitted changes that you don't want to lose and the changes that you want to revert to unmodified state.

Reverting local changes is an *irreversible* operation. Therefore, reverting local changes in SVN working copy via [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) must be done cautiously. Assume that you are working on a task and haven't yet committed some important changes you've been working on a couple of hours. But at the same time you have some changes in a file or directory that you want to revert. Carelessly running `svn revert . -R` at the root of working copy will revert *all* the uncommitted changes in the working copy.

Citing [SVNBook | `svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html)

> `svn revert` is inherently *dangerou*s, since its entire purpose is to
>   throw away data—namely, your uncommitted changes. Once you've
>   reverted, Subversion provides no way to get back those uncommitted
>   changes.
>
> If you provide no targets to `svn revert`, it will do nothing. To
>   protect you from accidentally losing changes in your working copy, `svn  revert` requires you to explicitly provide at least one target.

---

> Now while standing in Root i run the command svn.exe revert
>   --recursive AssemblyInfo.vb and the output i get is:

[`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) does not work this way. By default, it runs with `--depth=empty` to ensure that it won't revert more than the user intended. But running`svn revert` with `-R` is the same as running it with `--depth=infinity`. Generally speaking, in this particular case `--recursive` is an alias for `--depth=infinity` and its purpose is to help users revert all the local modifications (e.g. after invalid merge).

When you  run `svn revert` with `--recursive`, the tool expects you to specify a path to a directory in your working copy and the operation will revert *ALL* the changes that are in this directory and its childs. **There will be no effect if the command's target is a file.**

What you look for is `--targets` and a bit of scripting. For example, run the following commands in PowerShell console (I'm sure that it could be done more elegantly in PowerShell than in this example):

```
(dir -Path "files.html" -Recurse -File).FullName | Out-File -Encoding ASCII mytargets.txt
svn revert --targets mytargets.txt
```

`dir` is an alias of `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet in PowerShell. In this case it grabs the list of all files with name `files.html` and writes the full paths to `mytargets.txt` file. Then it runs `svn revert` that reads paths from `mytargets.txt` and revert local modifications made to the files.

I advise this approach instead of piping the output to `svn revert` because you can (and should) review the list of items that `svn revert` will process. This helps you ensure that you won't revert more that you actually intended.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux this can be done using combination of `find` and `xargs` commands from [findutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findutils):

```
find -name AssemblyInfo.vb | xargs svn revert
```

On Windows you can probably install and use [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) which contain these utilities.

Comment: While that would work it seems a bit overkill to install Cygwin to solve this issue, the big question is why dosen't `--recursive` work, how is it intended to be used?

Comment: `--recursive` is supposed to be used for reverting directories. In your case you are reverting individual files. For this particular directory layout you can also `svn.exe revert *\*\AssemblyInfo.vb`. It will revert both `AssemblyInfo.vb` files at once.

Comment: if i run `svn.exe revert *\*\AssemblyInfo.vb` on windows i get `svn: E155010: The node '...Root\*' was not found.`.